# NHibernate CacheException: StackExchange.Redis configuration string was not provided

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redis, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, stackexchange.redis

I'm setting up caching using Redis for NHibernate. I have followed the documentation on how to set up this. The only difference is I did not use the below implementation.

```
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.Redis.RedisCacheProvider, 
    NHibernate.Caches.Redis</property>
```

Instead, I use something like this:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(
            PostgreSQLConfiguration.PostgreSQL82.ConnectionString(
                    c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(connectionStringName))
                .Driver<NpgsqlDriverExtended>()
                .Dialect<NpgsqlDialectExtended>()
        )
        .Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AccountMap>()
                .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<UnderscoreColumnConvention>()
        )
        .Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<RedisCacheProvider>()
            .UseQueryCache()
            .UseSecondLevelCache());
```

I also added the below in web.config

```
<configSections>
    <section name="redis" type="NHibernate.Caches.StackExchangeRedis.RedisSectionHandler, NHibernate.Caches.StackExchangeRedis" />
</configSections>

<redis>
    <cache region="foo_bar" expiration="999" priority="4" />
</redis>
```

The only thing that I did not add is the below.

```
RedisCacheProvider.ConnectionSettings = new RedisCacheConnection("localhost", 6379) { { "allowAdmin", "true" }, { "abortConnect", "false" } };
```

I do not know where to place the above snippet. Even if I know where to place it, I'd rather want it to be set up in web.config, but I could not find anything that put me in that direction.

Please can anyone direct me in the right direction? I have tried also dependency injection but still having an issue that `StackExchange.Redis configuration string was not provided`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who might have this issue, I was able to figure this out. What you need to set Redis with NHibernate properly is to add the following configuration.

```
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Properties.Add("cache.default_expiration", "900");
    cfg.Properties.Add("cache.use_sliding_expiration", "true");
    cfg.Properties.Add("cache.configuration", "localhost:6379,allowAdmin=true,abortConnect=false");
})
```

As stated at [27.1. How to use a cache?](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/caches.html#NHibernate.Caches.ConfigurationProvider)

The final result will be something like the below.

```
return Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(
        PostgreSQLConfiguration.PostgreSQL82.ConnectionString(
                c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(connectionStringName))
            .Driver<NpgsqlDriverExtended>()
            .Dialect<NpgsqlDialectExtended>()
    )

    .Cache(c =>
        c.UseSecondLevelCache()
            .UseQueryCache()
            .ProviderClass<RedisCacheProvider>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Properties.Add("cache.default_expiration", "900");
        cfg.Properties.Add("cache.use_sliding_expiration", "true");
        cfg.Properties.Add("cache.configuration", "localhost:6379,allowAdmin=true,abortConnect=false");
    })
    .Mappings(m =>
        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AccountMap>()
            .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<UnderscoreColumnConvention>()
    );
```